# React Native, read a folder of files into an array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, image, directory, native

I am trying to create an array of images, but I don't want to have to type out each image location. Here is what I have for it.

```
var array = [
    require("./cards/card.png"), 
    require("./cards/card2.png")
  ]
```

I want to make it so I can just read through the whole cards folder and get each name into the array. How should I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can not do that. You can store path to image, and do smth like that:

```
const array = [
  "./cards/card.png", 
  "./cards/card2.png"
]

array.map(imgPath => <image src={imgPath} alt='arr item'/>)
```